# Specify width of the cell imageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

Is it possible to constraint the width of `[[cell imageView]` a standard `UITableViewCell`?
I've tried `[[cell imageView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]` but it has no effect.

**[EDIT]**

Otherwise, is it possible to change a `UIImage` size before adding it in the `UIImageView`?

Comment: There are literately thousands of categories implementations out there for scaling your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't simply set the image view's frame on a regular UITableViewCell, you could make a UITableViewCell subclass, and reposition the image view in `-layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use .transform method in UIView example

```
cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.65, 0.65);
```

//if you are subclassing UITableViewCell you can do this too

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(10,5,65,65);
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,5,65,65);
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    if (self.imageView.image) {
        //TODO: adjust the textLabel and detailTextLabel
    }

}
```

Comment: After much looking around to resize an imageview or UIView withing a table cell use the cGAffineTransform methods. eg myUiImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.65, 0.65);  subclassing and calling layout subviews did not work for me.

Comment: setting a transform on a cell's image view may get reset if you are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and the cell scrolls off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.

its width should not be changed, for that you have to create UITableViewCell subclass and you can change imageview in UITableViewCell and change width according to it.
or u can use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIImageView *imgView; 
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(100,0,100,62)];
    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
    imgView.tag = 55;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];
} 
else
{
    imgView = (id)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:55];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Image Fix Size:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[imgview setImage:image];
[cell addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

Comment: The purpose of the question is to avoid doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the in-built functionality to provide imageView for every cell. Its frame cannot be changed unless it is sub-classed.

However, you can add any of your own imageViews by simply adding the following code in the method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UIImageView* *myView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [myView setImage:image];
        myView.tag = 123;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:myView];
        [myView release];
    }
    else
    {
        myView = (UIImageView*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my swift solution of this problem

```
//
//  UITableVIewCellBasicWithFixedSizeImage.swift
//
//  Created by Andrew Ashurow on 4/28/16.
//  Copyright © 2016. All rights reserved.
//

class UITableVIewCellBasicWithFixedSizeImage: UITableViewCell {
        private let
        IMAGE_VIEW_WIDTH:CGFloat        = 27,
        TEXT_VIEW_LEFT_INSET:CGFloat    = 15

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            if let
                imageView = imageView,
                textLabel = textLabel{
                //set fixed image width
                imageView.frame = CGRect(
                    origin: imageView.frame.origin,
                    size: CGSize(
                        width: IMAGE_VIEW_WIDTH,
                        height: imageView.frame.size.height
                    )
                )
                imageView.contentMode = .Center
                imageView.autoresizingMask = .None

                //calculate textLabel inset
                textLabel.frame = CGRect(
                    origin: CGPoint(
                        x: imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width + TEXT_VIEW_LEFT_INSET,
                        y: textLabel.frame.origin.y
                    ),
                    size: textLabel.frame.size
                )

            }
        }
    }
```